# How to remove "Edit" from "EditText" context menu

Tags: android

I have an **EditText** which display context menu when your long press, which is OK.

The only issue, although, I need user to be able to "**select text**" and "**copy**" it. That is why I choosed **EditText** ( not **TextView**), but i don't want the user to be able to "Edit" text.

Notice, I set `"android:editable="false"` for **EditText**. So nothing happen if user choose "Edit" from context menu. But also, I don't want the "**Edit**" option to appear in the context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating TextView and making use of Clipboard.

```
TextView mTextView = new TextView(this);
registerForContextMenu(mTextView);


@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ((ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)).setText(mTextView.getText());
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `Edittext.setEnabled(false);` from the java code

You can also use `edittext.keyListener(null);`